# Chrome Extension - Returning no host permissions.I

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to set cookies on my `chrome-extension://` url, however I get a no host permissions error.

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "MyExtension",
  "description": "Do stuff",
  "version": "0.1",
  "icons": { "16": "icon.png",
           "48": "icon.png",
          "128": "icon.png" },
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>", "tabs", "background", "contextMenus", "cookies", "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["nav.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to set a cookie on `chrome-extension://` just use `localStorage`

Comment: Yeah, figured that out awhile ago, forgot to update the post.